# Promisify PhantomJS page method?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to use bluebird to promisify a phantomJS method:

```
page = require('webpage').create();
var checkWebpage = Promise.promisify(page.evaluate(function () {
         // do my thing  
}));

checkWebpage().then(function(result) {
  return result;
});
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
PHANTOM ERROR: TypeError: fn must be a function
```

Comment: Why do you want to promisify `page.evaluate`? It's a synchronous function. Also, you're trying to promisify the return value of `page.evaluate` which cannot be a function.

Comment: @ArtjomB I need to keep checking the page until a certain attribute has appeared. Is it better to poll?

Comment: The issue would be probably that the `page.evaluate` "callback" is sandboxed, so you probably need a wrapper function nevertheless. At least I don't see another way, but I haven't worked with bluebird yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promisify takes a function as an argument, you're giving it the return value of the function evaluated in the context of the page object. Wrap the argument in an another function if you mean to evaluate your initial function within the page, if not, just pass your function in as is.